# Redux Form component "onSubmitSuccess" Unit Test

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs

I am new to react, I need a help for writing a test case for Redux Form component "onSubmitSuccess",
below is the code

```
reduxForm({ form: "AddTagForm", 
  enableReinitialize: true,
  onSubmitSuccess: afterSubmit })

callback function,

export const afterSubmit = (dispatch) => dispatch(reset("AddTagForm"));
```

I need a help for writing a test case for afterSubmit method. Please help

Note: I am using jest with enzyme for unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

Write a unit test to check for a blank form. So call whatever submits the form (be it a button, directly calling the onSubmit method, etc.) and then use snapshot testing with Jest to confirm that whatever data was in the form before submit has been succesfully cleared. You can find more information on snapshot testing [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing)

Remember, a unit test should never depend on the code that it is testing to define what a successful result is. I.e, don't test the actual onSubmitSuccess method, but instead test what that method is doing. In this case, it is resetting the form, so test that the form has been successfully reset.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the response. Actually i am able to do unit test for onSubmit method, But while coming to coverage afterSubmit is not covering. Can you please tel me how to write a unit test case for resetting the form?, Thanks in advance

Comment: @Santhu No problem! I'm not sure how familiar with React unit testing you are, so if you need more clarification, please feel free to ask. What you need to do is shallowly render the redux-form connected component, populate it with some data, then call the onSubmit method, once you have called that method, you need to test that the form is then empty (i.e doesn't contain the data you populated it with). This will then provide coverage for that afterSubmit method.
Have a look at this https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html and the last link I posted.

Comment: yes lek i am new to unit case as well as react redux, I am struggling to find the solutions for this

Comment: If you give some examples for this it will really helpful for me

Comment: @Santhu can you post the unit test code which you already have?

Comment: describe("afterSubmit", () => {

  
  it("invokes afterSubmit", () => {
   

    const result = reset({type: "InputRadio"});
    
    result();

   
    expect(result).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});

Comment: I dont know its correct but i tried this to check function is called or not

Comment: Have you read the documentation that I have linked to. You need to write a snapshot unit test based on a shallow render of the component. Have a read of that documentation and let me know what you think.

Comment: Hi lek, yeah i red that information on the link given, But problem is afterSubmit method is in HOC there we are not using any wraper or snapshot. And i dont know how to use snapshots in HOC.

Comment: @Santhu can you post the code in your original question please.

Comment: export const onSubmit = ({
  Method1,
  Method12,
}) => async values => {
  Method1(values).then(() => {
    Method12();    // some functionality works after success
  });
};


export const afterSubmit = (result, dispatch) => dispatch(reset("AddTagForm"));  // call back from onSubmitSuccess to clear input fields

export default compose(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    {
      Method1,
      Method12
    }
  ),
  withHandlers({ onSubmit }),
  reduxForm({ form: "TestForm", 
  enableReinitialize: true,
  onSubmitSuccess: afterSubmit })
);